# how are http request processed by server

Tags: apache, http, xmlhttprequest

I am posting data from server to some api endpoints(etsy endpoints mostly).
I am sending the ids of products that are to be updated on etsy from browser as below:

```
    const update_products_to_shopify =  (pg,shop_id) => {
        for (let i in pg){

            if(pg.hasOwnProperty(i)){
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url:'index.php?option=com_cartproductfeed&task=etsyUploader.upload',
                    type:'post',
                    dataType:'json',
                    data:{products_ids: pg[i], shop_id:shop_id},

                    success: function (res) {

                        return false;
                    },

                    error: function (err) {

                    }
                });
            }

            setTimeout(function(){},2000);

        }
    };
```

here **pg** stands for product groups, each array of pg contains 7 product ids. and it is processed from server.

So if there are 700 products to be uploaded/updated then there will be 100 products group, for each products group, the request will be sent to server it will process it and sends back the response.

On each process, server will format data required for etsy api, post on listing api endpoints, process image data and sends it again to image upload endpoints, and process variation and sends it to variation upload endpoints.

What I am trying to ask is, is it okay to send the 100 requests at a time(which i am doing currently) or should i follow some other approach. I have pasted the image of request queue from the browser here.
[image]

Since I am unaware about the http request processing and its working mechanism, I would be very grateful to those who would help me design this process.
Thanks.

Comment: You could create an endpoint that receives the list of all the ID's and then update them all at once. This way it is done in a single request, and you do not have the HTTP overhead on each update, but only once.

Comment: @rotgers But if I do so, there will be execution time out for more than 7 products.